# Alternative to using options.CookieHttpOnly MVC Core

Tags: session, asp.net-core-mvc

Visual Studio 2017 tells me that using options.CookieHttpOnly is obsolete when dealing with a session. What shall I use instead? Here is the code part:

```
        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout =
            TimeSpan.FromMinutes(20);
           #pragma warning disable CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
            options.CookieHttpOnly = true;
           #pragma warning restore CS0618 // Type or member is obsolete
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

The option hasn't been removed; it's simply been moved. It's now `options.Cookie.HttpOnly`.

Comment: Thanks! Found the answer by myself after some searching